# Using akka-http client `entity.discardEntityBytes` with strict Unmarshaller

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

the akka-http client [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#using-the-future-based-api-in-actors) states the following:

> Be sure to consume the response entities
>   dataBytes:Source[ByteString,Unit] by for example connecting it to a
>   Sink (for example response.discardEntityBytes() if you don’t care
>   about the response entity), since otherwise Akka HTTP (and the
>   underlying Streams infrastructure) will understand the lack of entity
>   consumption as a back-pressure signal and stop reading from the
>   underlying TCP connection!

When using `singleHttpRequest` to get a `Future[HttpResponse]`, I am sometimes using an unmarshaller that was created using `Unmarshaller.strict`.

When using `Unmarhsaller[HttpEntity, T]`,

Looking at the akka source code, it seems that after using marshallers obtained using [`Unmarshaller.strict`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/unmarshalling/Unmarshaller.scala#L65), we should call `discardEntityBytes`, or make sure the unmarshaller calls that method, or consumes the bytes. When using `Unmarshaller[HttpEntity, T]`, we would need to make sure those bytes are consumed.

Is this a correct assumption?

Update:

This is the implementation of `Unmarshaller.strict`:

```
def strict[A, B](f: A ⇒ B): Unmarshaller[A, B] = Unmarshaller(_ => a ⇒ FastFuture.successful(f(a)))
```

Which calls `Unmarshaller.apply`, which ends up calling `withMaterializer`, which creates an anonymous `Unmarshaller`. See more  [on github](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/unmarshalling/Unmarshaller.scala#L55). No where in this implementation does the unmarshaller consumes or verifies the consumption of bytes from the entity, or calls `discardBytes`.

Answer (score 4):

`Unmarshall` with or without `strict` reads the response entity and gives you the option to convert the results into whatever case class you want. By doing so, you don't need to `discardEntityBytes`.

Akka-Http just like any other Akka based project, is stream based. Hence, it will need the a destination to its results, and otherwise, it will understand the lack of that destination as your client hasn't received the information requested and then it will apply back-pressure. From the docs:

> since otherwise Akka HTTP (and the underlying Streams infrastructure)
>   will understand the lack of entity consumption as a back-pressure
>   signal and stop reading from the underlying TCP connection!

Whenever you are using Unmarshall, you are reading the `Source` bytes and the method `discardEntityBytes` is nothing more than a `Sink` like `dev/null` and you don't need to append it to your calls. Unless you actually don't care about the returned entity.

Comment: I added some clarification on why I think `Unarsmaller` can be used without consuming the bytes, at least I cannot find that in the documentation. Nothing makes sure that the bytes are consumed by the Unmarshaller?

Comment: @simao I might be not understanding your comment as you intended, however, the main question is, how important is using the `discardEntityBytes` if you are using `Unmarshall` and I was saying you shouldn't not based on how `Unmarshall` works, but more like on how `discardEntityBytes` works. The later is a sink that ignores the response, you have to use it to avoid a default back-pressure when you don't need the bytes. By using Unmarshall, you need the bytes, hence, you shouldn't be using `discardEntityBytes`

Comment: Except if the `Unmarshaller` chooses to ignore the bytes and output something different instead. For example `implicit val unitFromEntityUnmarshaller: FromEntityUnmarshaller[Unit] = Unmarshaller.strict(_ => ())` This `Unmarshaller` is used in the case the http server returns `NoContent`, and I'd like to transform that response in a `Future[Unit]`.